# Apply scikitlearn clustering algorithms on networkx network graphs

Tags: python, network-programming, scikit-learn, social-networking, networkx

I have a network that looks like the one below (this is a standard NetworkX output, but the Gephi viz can show a structure) and I was wondering if I can do a scikitlearn ML clustering on a network.

[image]

Most of the scikitlearn tutorials / demos use blobs of points, but not exactly those interconnected by edges. I have not come across a source that uses scikit on network data.  I can ignore/remove the edges, then cluster - but I will lose valuable information on connectivity, especially in the dense subgraphs.  Or, should I work with an adjacency matrix and feed it into the scikit package? I am a little confused, and would appreciate some guidance!

PS: I am looking to run fuzzy c-means, hierarchical or spectral clustering on my network.

Comment: sklearn let's use pass a connectivity structure into its [`AgglomerativeClustering`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering). What kind of data do you have associated with the nodes that you want to cluster? Or are you really just trying to cluster the graph?